# How to keep one according tab opened always

Tags: javascript, jquery

Created simple accordion, which is working fine.

Issue found is : If am opening one accordion tab, if i click on it then it should not close.
if i opened another accordion then the before accordion should close and the new opened accordion should be opened only if I click on it again.

This is what I have tried.
In my implementation accordion tabs can be opened and close on its same click.

Jquery:

```
   $('.info').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function () {
       //Expand or collapse this panel
    $(this).toggleClass("open").next().slideToggle('fast');
       //Hide the other panels
    $(".accordion-toggle").not($(this)).removeClass("open");
    $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
});
```

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/etfs1L43/5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a condition check if clicked accordian has `class="open"` using below code -

```
if($(this).attr('class').indexOf('open')==-1)
   $(this).toggleClass("open").next().slideToggle('fast');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/etfs1L43/7/)**

**EDIT** - as suggested by Amin, we can use `.hasClass` method provided by jQuery like below

```
if(!$(this).hasClass('open'))   
  $(this).toggleClass("open").next().slideToggle('fast');
```

**[Demo with hasClass](http://jsfiddle.net/etfs1L43/11/)**

Comment: The OP wants the others to only open on second click once the default has closed on first.

Comment: you can also use `if($(this).hasClass('open'))`

Comment: "the new opened accordion should be opened only if I click on it again." this sentence is little confusing.. OP please clarify

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this fiddle.
I have just added a callback function to the slideDown call.

```
$('.info').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function () {
//Expand or collapse this panel

$(this).addClass("open").next().slideDown('fast',function(){
 $(".accordion-toggle").not($(this)).removeClass("open");

 $(".accordion-content").not($(this)).slideUp('fast');
});
//Hide the other panels

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/etfs1L43/9/

Answer (score 1):

i rewrote your js - since i understood your request, that you want to expand the clicked content only, if there is no current shown content...
http://jsfiddle.net/etfs1L43/12/

```
$(".accordion-toggle").on("click", function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
        $(".open").next().slideUp('slow');
        if (!$(".accordion-toggle").hasClass("open")) {
            $(this).addClass("open").next().slideDown('slow');
        } else {
            $(".open").removeClass("open");
        }
    }
});
```